# How do I reset Codeblocks to factory default

Tags: c++, codeblocks

[Gray Header File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgdrJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAnHj.png)

I was going to make a class in codeblocks, when I realised all of the text was in gray, this has never happened before only now, I'm not sure if it's due to the perspective or not. I have redownloaded codeblocks multiple times and have come to no avail. I am running Windows 11

Comment: Why don't you add `.cpp` or `.h` extension to your file names? It might be that your IDE can't recognize what kind of text you have written (which obviously is C++ text) because the files don't have any C++ related extension (e.g. `.cpp`, `.cc`, `.hpp`, etc).

Comment: Are your files really named with no file extension? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @starball I have named all my files correctly, it is giving me an error saying, "Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe', but failed!" It is also telling me it can't find the compiler even though it is set tp the correct compiler in the global toolchains

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. While you're at it, please- to the best of your ability in yoru circumstances- provide exact steps to reproduce as much of the issue as possible. See the instructions in [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Codeblocks looks at the file extensions to determine the syntax highlighting conventions. If you do not have an extension for your file then the text is black.